# Are the words biology and Ecology ever interchangeable?

Tags: ecology

I often hear people use the word "Ecology" when i think they mean "biology." This got me wondering: are the words ever interchangeable, or are these people really just that frequently using the wrong word?

My understanding is biology is the broader study of life while Ecology is the more specialized study of life interacting with other stuff (life + earth).

Comment: You pretty much nailed it with your definitions. Good guess. Wikipedia should also be able to help you

Comment: Ah... So you've heard people to use words despite they don't know what they mean?